# Remove all Jbuttons and passing the setText value to other variables

Tags: java, swing

I want to be able to remove all the JButton that is tied to b by just clicking on whichever of them and also to pass the value from the button that the user clicked to outside the loop. The code below only removes the button the user clicked on only.

```
for (File file : listOfFiles) {
                int fileCount = 0;
                if (file.isFile()) {    
                    JButton b = new JButton(String.valueOf(fileCount));
                    fileCount++;
                    b.setText(file.getName());
                    b.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(300, 40));
                    Panel.add(b);
                    frame.add(b);
                    b.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
                        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent e) {
                            b.setVisible(false);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i got your question right
you should probably create an array or ArrayList of Buttons.

If you want to delete all Buttons you got to Iterate through yourlist and delete all items.

If you want to receive the which button was clicked, you can call your list via

```
list.indexOf(ButtonObject);
```

to get a specific index of your button